# Kinds of types in functions

Tags: haskell

Take the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds #-}

data Nat = O | S Nat

class NatToInt (n :: Nat) where
    natToInt :: n -> Int

instance NatToInt O where
    natToInt _ = 0

instance (NatToInt n) => NatToInt (S n) where
    natToInt _ = 1 + natToInt (undefined :: n)
```

GHC informs us that it expects an `OpenKind` in the type specification of `natToInt` instead of a `Nat` and thus refuses to compile. This can be remedied by some kind casting:

```
data NatToOpen :: Nat -> *
```

and then replacing `n` with `NatToOpen n` in t the `natToInt`-s.

Question 1: is there some way to specify kinds other than `*` in any function without using type-level wrappers?

Question 2: It appears to me that non-class functions will happily work with types of any kind, for example:

```
foo :: (a :: *) -> (a :: *)
foo = id

bar = foo (S O)
```

but inside classes the compiler will complain about kind mismatches, as I described above. Why is that? It doesn't seem that non-class functions are properly polymorphic in kinds, because above I actually *specified* `*`, and it still works with `Nat`-s, as if the kinds were simply ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values always have types of kind `*` (possibly with some weird exceptions involving unboxing?), so there's nothing you can apply a function to or take as an argument that would have some other kind.

In your final example, you're applying `foo` to the unlifted version of `Nat`: the values are `S` and `O`, and their *type* is `Nat`, which has kind `*`. In the class definition, you give `Nat` as a kind using a signature, which means the lifted version, where `S` and `O` are *types*.

The `NatToOpen` type is just using phantom types in the usual way, but with a phantom type parameter of a non-`*` kind.

This distinction is not new with `DataKinds`, either. For example, there are no values whose type is `Maybe :: * -> *`, as distinct from the type `forall a. Maybe a :: *`, which is the type of `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now... I completely forgot that I still get the plain old ADT.